# Efficient way to count the number of elements of a kind in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I'm given a matrix in the form of an array like this:

```
[3 2 3]
[4 5 6]     =>   [3 2 3 4 5 6 7 3 9]
[7 3 9]
```

I'm also given the number of rows and number of columns in the original matrix (here 3, 3) and the element whose occurrences need to be counted (say 3).

Now I want to count the number of times this element occurs in a particular region.

The region is defined like this for a 3X3 matrix:

```
[3 2 3]      [3 2 3]
[4 5 6]  =>  [4 5 6]
[7 3 9]      [7 N 9]
```

and for a 5X5 matrix:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]      [1 2 3 4 5]
[6 7 8 9 0]      [6 7 8 9 0]
[1 3 5 7 9]  =>  [1 3 5 7 9]
[2 4 6 8 0]      [2 4 N 8 0]
[9 6 3 1 2]      [9 N N N 2]
```

The region in which I want to count the occurrences is the region not filled with N. I hope the pattern is clear.

This is how I did it:

```
int count_elem (int arr[], int rows, int cols, int elem) {
    // creating the 2D matrix
    int mat[][] = new int[rows][cols];
    int arr_in = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = arr[arr_in];
            arr_in++;
        }
    }

    // counting the element
    int midCol = cols/2, colLen = rows, count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<cols; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i<colLen; i++) {
            if (mat[i][j] == elem) count++;
        }
        if (j<midCol) colLen--;
        else  colLen++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Some constraints:

- It's always a square matrix
- Number of rows or columns is always odd

I want to know if there's any better approach to count the given element, one that maybe doesn't need me creating the matrix from the array.

I want to know if my algorithm is correct, so please ignore any mistakes in my code.

Comment: Just to understand: the region is not given to you in a matrix. It is defined as the triangular region under the middle point of the matrix? Or rather, as anything not in that triangle?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : No the region isn't given in the matrix, it follows a pattern, where the number of elements to be ignored increases steadily upto middle column and then drops in the same way

Comment: `better approach` - define a _measure_. Readability? "speed"? (Do not bother to copy the data. Handle the data as _n-1_ contiguous parts for an array of _n²_ elements.)

Comment: This is not a code review site.

Comment: `I want to know if my algorithm is correct, so please ignore any mistakes in my code.` As you only specify your algorithm by the code presented: YES. (I can argue it terminates, and you asked to ignore mistakes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better solution than creating a matrix from an array. 
You can simple calculate the array index from the x- and y- coordinates in the matrix with

```
x + (y * dimX)
```

Also there is no need for the parameters: number of rows and column. That's because of you condition: rows = columns. You get the number of rows and columns over the square from the array length.
My solution:

```
static int count_elem(int arr[], int elem) {
    int rows = (int) Math.sqrt(arr.length);
    int cols = (int) Math.sqrt(arr.length);

    int midCol = cols / 2, colLen = rows, count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < colLen; i++) {
            if (arr[j + (i * rows)] == elem) count++;
        }
        if (j < midCol) colLen--;
        else colLen++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I hope my solution fits your idea.

Answer (score 0):

lets call the number we are searching for `x`, then we can:

```
int array[1000000];

int numOfPatterns(int x, int n){               
    int count = 0, jump = 1, int finish = n*n;
    while(jump <= n/2){
        int lim = finish - jump;                         
        for(int i = finish - n + jump; i < lim; i++)
            if(array[i] == x) count++;
        jump = jump + 1;
        finish = finish - n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

this is probably the most efficient way to count some number following that pattern. Here you look only at the indexes of the array that should be looked, ignoring the others.

This is a O(n^2) solution but in fact, following that lookup pattern, it will always do something like O(n^2/4) operations.

a little about the code:

- `n` is the dimension of the matrix
- `jump` is the variable who tells where it should start looking at each row of the matrix
- `while(jump <= n/2)` means that it will stop after the case `1 2 X 3 4`
- `lim` is just where the search will end
- `finish` is the index of the ending position of each row of the matrix in the array